# How can i hide certain table column in a HTML table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a html table which is as follows

```
<table class="report">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td >col1</td>
        <td >col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>R2</td>
        <td >2/17</td>
        <td >{2/17}</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see , after col3 , all subsequent columns are empty.
I want to show only first three columns and hide the rest.
How can i achieve this using CSS.
I dont have control over HTML table so i can not modify it.

Thanks

Comment: are you using jquery ? if yes, see my post... no need to modify the html

Comment: now you have accepted mat's answere... but now i have a question for you... why you have the empty td's ? because the solution of mat is kinda strict and cant really be changed dynamicly only if you use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) what also need js ^^

Comment: This table is generate from a XLS file by using apache poi. which also generates empty columns and generated HTML is shown in  a web app using Iframe where i dont have access to JS. so i plan to inject this CSS along with generated html. BTW thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem other one like charlie don't see that im just trying to help and than devote posts to ... in the end i don't know what he tries to achieve with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nEQ6g/1/

*EDIT - From my knowledge `nth-child` and `visability: hidden` don't play nice together. For what you want, you'd need to use `display: none;` - based upon the code I've provided you.

CSS:

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

table tr td:nth-child(n+4){
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
td:nth-child(n+4) {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZRvx/

I think that that is the most clearest way to do it.

Comment: I dont want to modify the HTML

Comment: If he did this, he wouldn't even need nth-child. You'd simply hide the class with the new class on it..

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this...

**CSS**

```
td:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(7)
{
   display:none;
}
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OPOCaDAv/1/edit)**

Comment: How is it different from @StuartLC's answer?

Comment: This wouldn't work if the cells were to dynamically increase. Also it's a lot of CSS, that could be achieved in one reference using n+4

Comment: @abhitalks It's not.   Mine was first (see, unedited).   His was changed later to match this one.

Comment: @Mat-visual there is *always* a *what if*...  what if he adds more cells, deletes some, changes things, etc.  My answer simply does what the OP asked for.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Ok, but it still stands, instead of writing so much CSS, you can write one line: td:nth-child(n+4) and save yourself time and code.

Comment: @Charlie74: Fair enough! My bad, I didn't notice.

Comment: @Mat-visual: Yes. And your answer covers that. And I too +1ed that. But, still this answer is *not incorrect* because, Op didn't specifically ask for one-liner, nor does he mentions possibility of more columns and flexibility. Talking about flexibility, what if there is one more column added later on which needs to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 `nth child` selector, e.g.

```
td:nth-child(4),td:nth-child(5), ...
{
   display:none;
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhdQ9/1/)

Comment: this will hide the third col. i want to show first three and hide columns after third column.

Comment: Yeah, my counting sucks. But you get the idea.

Comment: someone downvoted?? Just change 3 to 4 and it should work. Though, doing so easy things in CSS3 isn't recommended at all (i sometimes use lynx thats why I prefer CSS2)

Answer (score 0):

I've got no idea what's the intent, the reason or the audience but if you append a data attribute to each column cell...

```
<td data-col="1"></td>
```

You can then use jQuery to hide all cells that belong to a specific column...

```
$('td[data-col=1]').hide ();
```

You could also use the ':nth-child ()' css pseudo class but it is not supported by some IE  browsers

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to show the first 3 colums and hide the rest of the colums in the row you might want to use:

```
tr > td:nth-child(n+4)
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will start at the index of 4 and will loop through the rest and will hide them.

With `visibility: hidden;` you will still keep the spacing it had.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mZHV/)

Answer (score -1):

this is a jquery solution. it checks if there is only a whitespace in there... if yes, it hides it.

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == "&nbsp;")
      $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: The OP asked for a CSS solution

Comment: but he also sayed he don't want to edit his html... in this case there is no other posibility. so maybe he uses jquery or some like this and than this can be helpful

Comment: I agree that giving the OP choices is a good thing.  He *asked* for CSS, but that may be because he isn't aware of other methods available.   Why not give him options?

Comment: there are no options... the only thing what he can do is, edit html or use javascript/jquery or php :)

Comment: @Dwza LOL you know that's completely wrong, right?   This is easily done via CSS.

Comment: just to make you get me right: he has a html file with a table... of course he can easy change it with css but its not dynamicly! and without js you never get it dynamicly! and he sayed he don't want to edit html. i guess the reason is because he has more than one file or not all fields are same... so i provided him with this solution... if you know a way how to dynamicly handle this... hey tell me, im openminded for new stuff Charlie