# Problems hiding a table column in CSS

Tags: css

I found how I can hide a table column in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682536/how-can-i-hide-certain-table-column-in-a-html-table-using-css):

```
<style>
  table tr th:nth-child(4){ display:none; }
  table tr td:nth-child(4){ display:none; }
</style>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work correctly when I use `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes. On [this table](http://zorl.net/cols.php) the content of some cells is missing, as is the right border.

[image]

Notice that the content and right border are missing each time the row starts with a `rowspan`.

How can I hide table columns correctly when I use `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/raxwvvdj/ its working for me

Comment: @vasanth - Yes I know in your test it works. But I particularly said (twice!) in my question that it doesn't work correctly with `rowspan` and `colspan`.

Comment: @0_o - No, that won't work. It will make the content invisible, but the cell border will still be visible, and it will still use space.

Comment: try using `opacity:0` instead of `display:none` for last element [example](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/mq2uyuv9/1/)

Comment: it is not taking extra space i have added a `div` fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/mq2uyuv9/3/

Comment: @0_o - That shows the border, but not the content. If you look at the code, the resolution line has "10 bits", "12 bits" and "12 bits". The last one is correctly hidden, but the first "12 bit" data should be visible, quod non. Thanks for your comment, though.

Comment: @0_o - I didn't say `opacity:0` would take *extra* space, but it will take the same space as without it. The table layout would look exactly the same, just the cells would be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `nth-child` for `tr` also
I hope it will solve your problem.

```
<style>
  table tr:nth-child(4) th:nth-child(1){ display:none; }
  table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1){ display:none; }
</style>
```

Here is the code snippet.

```css
table,th,td{border:1px solid black;}
table.new tr:nth-child(4) td{display:none;}
table.new tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2){display:none;}
```

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Mar</td>
    <td >$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

</table>

<span>table after hiding row/column with  rowspan/colspan </span>
 <table class="new">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Mar</td>
    <td >$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
table tr th:nth-child(3), table tr td:nth-child(3){
 display: none;
}
```

No rule knows "n". You need to put a number inside the nth-child() method.

So for your example link I used n = 3

See my simple example:
https://jsfiddle.net/cvaxzvey/

Comment: "You need to put a number inside the nth-child() method". Read this documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: I removed the "n", which indeed doesn't have a function here. Doesn't change anything. However, "n" is defined, and even necessary if you want for instance every third line in a table in a different color: "3n".

Comment: Sorry your are right with the defined n. Your link to your example does not have 4 cols, so it has no effect here. Try 3??